# How to test if a variable is initialized?

Tags: c++

How do you test if a certain variable has been initialized using an if statement.

Thanks everybody. I wasn't necessarily needing to test if it was initialized. So I received a solution and information about uninitialized variables as well.

Comment: @Kevin I'm trying to find one. Not sure what "initialized" *means* in the OP's context.

Comment: Writing "You know what I'm trying to ask" already shows that's it not clear what you're asking but you're hoping that somebody is smart enough to figure it out

Comment: @WhozCraig it means this: `int i; //not initialized` `int i=0; //initialized`

Comment: And for everyone else I think he is looking for php's isset() in C++

Comment: @Kevin so indeterminate value detection. Got it. Not entirely convinced that is what the OP means for sure, but it makes a lot more sense then the posted question.

Comment: Sorry I updated it some. It seemed simple enough to me at the time

Comment: Could it be set to NULL and tested for that? If it's type double?

Comment: No, only pointers can be `NULL`. You can set a `double` (or `float`, for that matter) to a NaN instead. Using a NaN in calculations will yield another NaNs, so you'll know that you did something wrong.

Comment: The site is pretty great. How do I show appreciation to my answer-ers?

Comment: By marking an answer as your accepted answer. This should be the answer that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you cannot and its is a bad practice to use uninitialized variables.

You may use something like this:

```
int x = -1;
....
rest of your code
....
if( x == -1 )
{
}
```

in the above example it is assumed that under program execution `x` will never be set to `-1`. If it is -1 then it is uninitialized.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way of knowing if a local non-static variable is initialized or not. However, global variables, as well as local `static` variable are always initialized (global and static local variables that are not explicitly initialized are zero-initialized by the compiler run-time system).

To not have to worry about it, always initialize local variables.

You might want to read about [`std::once_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag) and [`std::call_once`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once).

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, but you can set it to some initial value that indicates that it needs to be initialized again.

Comment: Ahh seems very helpful, thank you. So maybe set it to some weird number. Cool

Answer (score 1):

Global/static zero-fill not withstanding, the simple answer is this:

**You detect "uninitialized" variables when you're *writing* the code; not *running* it.**

You at least appear to be trying to "detect" an *indeterminate value* condition. Assuming local variables in function or loop-scope:

```
int a;
int b = a;
```

That simple little snippet is not defined behavior. Ask yourself what is `b` after this code executes? You think its whatever `a` is? Well then what is `a`? Don't know? Neither does anyone else, and that is the point. Its indeterminate, and if `a` is indeterminate, so then must be `b`.

An even simpler example:

```
int *p;

if (p) { do-something }
```

So.. does `do-something` execute? Are you *sure* about that ?

You avoid this by *always* initializing your variables *before* they're ever evaluated. A decent compiler, appropriately configured, will warn you if your code *may* evaluate something without it being set, but you can avoid it yourself by taking the steps to see it doesn't happen in the first place. Always initialize your variables. If they're objects in C++ they can self-initialize, but for types that have no default construction, you need to take the matter in to your own hands. In the process you never encounter this problem and your code will be further down the path to being well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly possible.

You may initialize it with a unique '*invalid*' value (so it is *initialized*).

`-1` for a `int` which should contain positive value.
`nullptr`(or `NULL`) for a pointer which should contain data.

An other method is to use additional data to keep track of uninitialized value.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : hasBeenSet(false) {}

    bool isInitialized() const { return hasBeenSet; }
    void set(int value) { hasBeenSet = true; myInt = value; }
    int get() const
    {
        if (!isInitialized()) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Not initialized");
        }
        return myInt;
    }
private:
    bool hasBeenSet;
    int myInt;
};
```